# How to obtain regularity when my app starts

Tags: android, animation, view

when I execute my app, I prepare some animation by code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

private Animation buscarAnimation2 = null;
private Animation buscarAnimation3 = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    RelativeLayout RL=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);


    buscarAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.boton2);
    buscarAnimation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.boton1);

    RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_trad);
                    TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_rell);
                    TextView t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_cub);
                    TextView t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_busq);

                    t1.setText(getString(R.string.main_trad));
                    t2.setText(getString(R.string.main_rell));
                    t3.setText(getString(R.string.main_cub));
                    t4.setText(getString(R.string.main_busq));

                    ImageButton b= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                    b.startAnimation(buscarAnimation2);
                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        }
                    });
                    ImageButton b2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
                    b2.startAnimation(buscarAnimation3);
                    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton b3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton03);
                    b3.startAnimation(buscarAnimation2);
                    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                    }
                    });


                    ImageButton b4= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton02);
                    b4.startAnimation(buscarAnimation3);
                    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                }
                    });
                }
            }); 
}
```

And happens that sometimes when I execute my app, I don´t view the animation, if the animation last 4 seconds I see a black theme and then the last second or maybe the last 2 seconds of the animation. Is like if it has trouble loading or something...

So how can I do to avoid this one, or maybe I am doing something wrong

EDITED THE CODE.

Answer (score 0):

How about starting the animation in `onResume` instead? At that point you're sure the Activity is visible (and running). Something like:

```
private Animation buscarAnimation1 = null;
private Animation buscarAnimation2 = null;
private Animation buscarAnimation3 = null;
private Animation buscarAnimation4 = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Other initialization code.

    buscarAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.boton1);
    buscarAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.boton2);
    buscarAnimation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.boton2);
    buscarAnimation4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.boton1);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ImageButton b1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    b1.startAnimation(buscarAnimation1);
    ImageButton b2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
    b2.startAnimation(buscarAnimation2);
    ImageButton b3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton03);
    b3.startAnimation(buscarAnimation3);
    ImageButton b4= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton02);
    b4.startAnimation(buscarAnimation4);
}
```

Comment: In this case it wouldn't run unless the app is moved to the background and brought up again, without being killed in the middle.

Comment: If you look at the Android documentation for Activities, you'll see that `onResume()` is invoked everytime (even the first) an activity is brought into focus.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) to your layout, and override it's [onGlobalLayoutListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) method to call your animation, as that is called once the layout has been drawn completely.

Comment: I edit above the code... but now the animation doesn´t start! If you can help me... THANKS!